# Jmeter: What is the actual difference between two tests which ran for different Time Duration (only hold load time changes)?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

#### Test 1:

> Ultimate Thread Group= 1500
>
> Http Sampler (Only Login Requests)
>
> Total Test Duration= 5 mins (held load for 3 min)
>
> Constant throughput timer=100/sec.

#### Output of Test 1:

[image]

#### Test 2:

> Same as Test 1 but load held for 5 mins.

#### Output of Test 2:

[image]

#### Question:

During the "hold load time", how many Login Requests session are alive? Say suppose, During Hold Load time (3 min), almost 18,000 login Requests are sent over for 1500 users.

Comment: What do you think the key differences are?

Comment: Edited the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 1500. During hold time only 1500 requests will be kept alive. It depends on many factors and one of the factor is whether you used "Cookie Manager" in your scripts. If "Clear cookie each iteration" checkbox is checked then every session or cookies will be cleared after each iteration. So At the hold time only 1500 requests will be alive concurrently.If "CLear cookie each iteration" is not checked then all those requests will be send using exactly 1500 different session ids. So in both case the number of active sessions will be limited to 1500.